# how can git remote repository automatically stores email address of whoever fork or clones a branch?

Tags: git, github, github-api

how can git remote repository public or private automatically stores email address of when someone forks or clones a branch from any branch?

or this feature isn't there ? for a github user I would need to get online to github.com to see if someone has forked my branch and I may never know who has cloned my branch .

the only way i see I can get to know when someone makes a pull request!

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Comment: of course, isn't it?))) many thanx)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the GitHub API you could list the forks of your repository. Once you've done so, you can request the user's profile from the GitHub API and only if they have an email specified can you get the user's email address. If they don't have one, you're out of luck. The API documentation about each of these different endpoints is very good, so I will not reproduce in detail the exact steps you will need to take. Needless to say, I doubt many users will take kindly to you doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can only control your own *`email`*, when commit changes. Also you can assign *`name`/`emails`* of committers, when you import the project from *svn/cvs* (as far as I remember). But if a user didn't specify his *`email`* and pushed into a repo, even on *GitHub* that email won't be changed unless the *DB* of that repo be reconstructed. When the repository is being forken, all commit *DB* is forken too, including commiter's *`name`, `email`*, and a commit *`message`*.

According to the *GitHub* you are allowed not to be online to see weither a person forks yuor repo. It will be seen as a nocite, and you can see the fork tree by clinking on a number of forks at the top left corner of your repository (The information is valid on begin of 2014 year).